# Is it possible to share huge data between projects when the data is installed by Nuget?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, maven, nuget

I found that nuget seems to always install packages under the folder of the visual studio project.
It is not feasible for me because the package that I'm going to distribute contains huge amount of data. I don't want to make a copy of that whenever I add that package to a new visual studio project.
I want that data to be shared between projects. Since it is shared, if one project removed that package, the data should stay there until I explicitly tell the system to remove it.

Is there any way that can deal with this kind of problem?

I heard that Maven installs packages in a global location and it doesn't have such a problem. How about using Maven to install .NET libraries, is that possible? What would be the potential problems?

Answer (score 1):

To upload and store your .NET artefacts you'll need a Maven repository manager like  [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/). Good news is that these are capable of storing files of any type.

If you don't fancy converting your build process over to Maven, I'd recommend the following  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540840/how-do-you-integrate-ivy-with-msbuild/6556344#6556344) on using [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) with MSBuild. All Maven clients appear to cache their downloads for use across projects (They're basically intelligent downloaders)

The upcoming 2.0 version of [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) promises integration with NuGet. I'm expecting better .NET support from Maven in the future.